# Change Button icon during runtime

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have activity with button inside GridLayout that is defined like this:

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/btnOpion4"
   android:layout_columnWeight="1"
   android:layout_rowWeight="1"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:drawableStart="@drawable/btnSend"/>
```

To be able to show icon on that button i had to create drawable xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_send"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_send"
        android:state_focused="true" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_send" />
</selector>
```

And all of this is working just fine...

Problem is, how can i change image from code behind?
For example if user click on some option, then change icon on this button?

EDIT:
Can I find that drawable by it's ID, and change icon? 
Something like `var btnsendDraw = FindViewById(Resource.Drawable.btnSend);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that by using the `SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` method found in the `Button` class.

In your case, I would create another drawable file with my other background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_sent"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_sent"
        android:state_focused="true" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_sent" />
</selector>
```

and let's call it: `btnSent`.

Now in your code, when you want to change the image just do:

```
var drawable = GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.btnSent);
btn1.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null);
```

This method gets the 4 different Drawables: left, top, end & bottom in this specific order. Since you only want to replace the **start** you will set the first parameter.

Note: `left` and `start` are "the same".

More about this method [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))

At the end you should have something like this:

[image]

Hope this helps.-